# Redirect top-level domain except for one page in Drupal

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two top-level domains pointing to my Drupal installation, abc.com and xyz.com.

I'd like to force all pages to use abc.com, EXCEPT for one page (node), which should always use xyz.com.

I've tried a bunch of different .htaccess, none seem to work. This is the closest I've gotten:

```
# Redirect abc.com/path/to/my/page to xyz.com/path/to/my/page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/my/page$ http://www.xyz.com$1 [R,L,NC]

# Redirect xyz.com to www.abc.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The above works for the whole site redirect, but when you go to abc.com/path/to/my/page it redirects to the main page, abc.com. I also tried this:

```
# Redirect abc.com/path/to/my/page to xyz.com/path/to/my/page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/my/page$ http://www.xyz.com/path/to/my/page [R,L,NC]
```

But that just gave me an error about too many redirects to xyz.com/path/to/my/page.

Any ideas? I'm not sure if my .htaccess code is wrong, or if it has to do with Drupal's clean URL functions, or what.

Here's the full Drupal .htaccess file:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_initialize_variables() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
php_flag register_globals                 off
php_flag session.auto_start               off
php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations.
ExpiresActive On

# Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
ExpiresDefault A1209600

<FilesMatch \.php$>
# Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
# headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
# headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
# fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
# problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
ExpiresActive Off
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect abc.com/path/to/my/page to xyz.com/path/to/my/page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(path/to/my/page)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

# Redirect xyz.com to www.abc.com (except for /path/to/my/page)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/my/page$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
# includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
# Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
# as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
# above.
#
# NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
# not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
# <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
#
# If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
# directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
# downloaded.
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

# If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
# can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
# URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
# RewriteBase /drupal
#
# If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
# uncomment the following line:
# RewriteBase /

#custom redirects (there are lots of these, all are specific paths used on an old site mapped to their respective pages on the new, reorganized site)
RewriteRule ^specific/old/path/$ http://www.abc.com/corresponding/new/path [R=301,L]    
#end custom redirects

# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
# index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
# Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

# Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

# Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

<FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
# Serve correct encoding type.
Header set Content-Encoding gzip
# Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code generates a loop. `abc.com/path/to/my/page` redirect to `xyz.com/path/to/my/page`, but all xyz urls are redirect to abc.com, so it would redirect back to `abc.com/path/to/my/page`, over and over again.

```
# Redirect abc.com/path/to/my/page to xyz.com/path/to/my/page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(path/to/my/page)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

# Redirect xyz.com to www.abc.com (except for /path/to/page)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/my/page$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.abc.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The rule in your first code was incorrect, redirecting `abc.com/path/to/my/page` to `abc.com/` (and that didn't create a loop).

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/my/page$ http://www.xyz.com$1 [R,L,NC]
```

This was because $1 reference to the first pair of parentheses, but you didn't have any. Secondly you needed to add a `/` before it, or it would redirect to `xyz.compath/to/my/page`

Comment: Thanks for tackling this! Here's what happens when I implement your code: http://www.abc.com/path/to/my/page < Renders page (should redirect to xyz.com/path/to/my/page) | 
http://www.xyz.com/path/to/my/page < Redirects to abc.com/index.php | 
http://www.xyz.com/misc/path < Redirects to abc.com/misc/path

Comment: Oops, I had a typo in the code! How embarrassing. Here's what happens now: abc.com/path/to/my/page < flash of redirecting correctly to xyz.com/path/to/my/page, then goes to abc.com/index.php

Comment: This makes me suspect there is some other code inside your htaccess. Could you add that to your original question?

Comment: You're amazing. I wish I could do more than just up-vote your answer and mark it as solved! A million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this "page" is a file, then you might need to do it this way. I used this to keep all Drupal files served from the original server, then forward all non-file traffic to the new site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?iradvocates\.org$ [NC]
```